# Flutter FirebaseMessaging onBackgroundMessage Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app with firebase with push notifications so the app was running but after I used "flutter clean" this error appears without changing and piece of code

```
E/flutter (14812): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (14812): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.registerBackgroundMessageHandler (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:180:53)
E/flutter (14812): #1      FirebaseMessagingPlatform.onBackgroundMessage= (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart:102:16)
E/flutter (14812): #2      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:73:31)
E/flutter (14812): #3      main (package:mitaa/main.dart:37:21)
```

the error appears in the package firebase_messaging: ^11.2.6

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

```
    Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).